# converting error messages from mongoose validation to user friendly messages

Tags: node.js, forms, validation, mongoose, ejs

Hello I am a beginner trying to learn node
I am trying to validate the data users entered in a registration page
This is my mongoose schema

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({     

    fname:{type:String,
        required:[true,"enter a first name"]}, 
    lname:{type:String,
        required:[true,"enter a last name "]},
    email:{type:String,
        required:[true,"email is required"],
        unique:true,
        trim:true,
        lowercase:true,
    validate(value){
        if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
            throw new Error("Email is invalid");
        }

    }
    }, 
    pass:{type:String,required:[true,"please enter a passkey"],minlength:[8,"enter atleast 8 characters"]} 

});
```

as you can see i am trying to validate some fields and check for errors

```
usersave.save((err,doc)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.render("register",{err:err}
    }
    else{console.log(doc);res.send("success")}
});
```

i am getting the following error messages in my console if user enters wrong data in the registration form:-

```
Error: users validation failed: fname: enter a first name, lname: enter a last name , pass: please enter a passkey, email: Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `ar@gmail.com`
    at ValidationError.inspect (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:718:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:287:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1910:40)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:299:10)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:309:61)
    at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\index.js:75:21
    at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4824:16
    at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4847:21
    at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:494:16
    at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\kareem\index.js:246:48
    at next (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\kareem\index.js:167:27)
    at next (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\kareem\index.js:169:9)
    at Kareem.execPost (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
    at _handleWrapError (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21) {
  errors: {
    fname: ValidatorError: enter a first name
        at validate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1217:13)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1200:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1145:14)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2392:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'fname',
      value: '',
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    lname: ValidatorError: enter a last name
        at validate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1217:13)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1200:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1145:14)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2392:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'lname',
      value: '',
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    pass: ValidatorError: please enter a passkey
        at validate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1217:13)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1200:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1145:14)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2392:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'pass',
      value: '',
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    email: ValidatorError: Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `ar@gmail.com`
        at validate (D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1217:13)
        at D:\.UC\eb Development\react-practice\authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1192:24
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'unique',
      path: 'email',
      value: 'ar@gmail.com',
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'users validation failed'
}
```

I want to be able to notify the users in the registration page what is it that they are doing wrong
i am getting the error messages and passing the error object to the registration page for re-rendering
this time displaying errors

the error object is containing the following info when i am passing it to the register.ejs

```
ValidationError: fname: enter a first name, lname: enter a last name , pass: please enter a passkey, email: Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `ar@gmail.com`
```

I want to display only error messages in the registration page how do i do that from the above information?
or is there any other way to display errors in frontend?

Comment: It Is better to set 'required: true' in your model schema and then to manage validation and messaging in your routers. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is through `npm express-validator` you can read about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator)

Then include it in your router file then validate though router middleware
like so:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post(
  '/',
  [
    //account details validation
    check('fname', 'Enter a First Name')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check('lname', 'Enter a Last name')
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
  check('email', 'type is required')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
     const errors = validationResult(req);
   //Check if there are errors 
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    //If so Send response status with the error message
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ status: false, data: errors.array()[0].msg });
    }
//... Rest of code is here ... 
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ status: false, error: error.message });
    }
  }
);
```

I recomend you to read about express routing and passing response status to your front end

Must say the response is up to your implementation you can also use

```
res.send(errors.array()[0].msg)
```

to just send the message itself.
In the code above i used json obj and response status to distinguish between errors types.
It's all up to your decision, hopefully this makes sense.
Good Luck